# How to make a installable PWA using vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, progressive-web-apps

I want to make my vue app installable via chrome/firefox using a button **(to show a pwa install prompt)**

```
<button @click="install">install</button>

var deferredPrompt
methods: {
  install() {
      deferredPrompt.prompt()
      deferredPrompt.userChoice.then((choiceResult) => {
          if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
              console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt')
          } else {
              console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt')
          }
          deferredPrompt = null
      })  
  }    
}
```

Once i build the app and its online, i click the button and got deferredPrompt null on console.
**What im missing?**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 8):

It looks like you don't have a [`beforeinstallprompt`](https://web.dev/customize-install/#beforeinstallprompt) event listener on the `window` object.

In vuejs, you'll need to do that in the `created()` event, for example:

```js
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      deferredPrompt: null
    };
  },
  created() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
      this.deferredPrompt = e;
    });
  },
  methods: {
    async install() {
      this.deferredPrompt.prompt();
    }
  }
};
```

Also, you should only show the install button only when the `beforeinstallprompt` event has been fired, and `deferredPrompt` has been set. Otherwise, the button will be visible but not do anything.

Check out https://medium.com/js-dojo/promoting-your-vue-js-pwa-installation-6bd112342c19 for more detail.

Comment: line 64 is this.deferredPrompt.prompt(); @PeteLe Im using your exact code